# How to use local variable in linq query in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an array of integers say `int[] vals`.

I want to use linq query to get a list of points from this array of ints.

For example if i have array like this:

```
vals = new int[]{20,25,34};
```

I want my list of points as

```
var points = List<Point>{new Point(1,20),new Point(2,25),new Point(3,34)};
```

I want to use  a local variable which is incremented by 1 for all int values in my array which will be the x value of my point.

How can I achieve this result using LINQ in C# ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the 2nd overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
var list = vals.Select((val, idx) => new Point(idx + 1, val)).ToList();
```

where `idx` is the `index` of `val` in `vals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vals = new int[]{20,25,34};
var x = 1;
var points = vals.Select((val) => new Point(x++,val)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Downvoter, could you comment? The OP asked for using a local variable in the query, which is what I do...

Answer (score 0):

Or a third option - get an ordinal enumeration and project using that and your original array.

```
var points = Enumerable.Range(1, vals.Count())
    .Select(i => new Point(i, vals[i - 1])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var vals = new int[] { 20, 25, 34 };
        int i = 0;
        var points = vals.ToList().ConvertAll(delegate(int v) { return new Point(++i, v); });
```